# How to avoid SCOBY in the Kombucha bottle? (second fermentation)

Tags: bottling, secondary-fermentation, kombucha

I am a kombucha brewer, and for a long time I have been trying to avoid SCOBY formation in the bottle during the second fermentation.
Does anyone know some way to do this?

Comment: Not sure it's possible.  SCOBY does what she wants.  She likes to make floating pancakes.  The best you might hope for is a high fill with a super narrow neck to keep the SCOBY as small as possible.

Comment: @dmtaylor: this seems a good answer, why don't you move it into a real answer, esp. since no-one else seems to come up with something alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure it's possible. SCOBY does what she wants. She likes to make floating pancakes. The best you might hope for is a high fill with a super narrow neck to keep the SCOBY as small as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You could heat treat / pasteurise the kombucha in the bottle, (once it's done carbonating).

Obviously this would kill off the beneficial bacteria, but it's those bacteria that make the floaty bits.